# How can I line up three items horizontally and have 2nd and 3rd right justified?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ViewCell that looks like this:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="bBtn" NoTap="true">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Label Text="XX" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
         <Label HorizontalOptions="End" Text="{Binding BBtnLabel}" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Stepper x:Name="bBtnStepper" Maximum="10" Minimum="0" ValueChanged="bBtnStepperValueChanged" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

This displays as:

```
XX 123               [Stepper Here]
```

The effect I would like to achieve is:

```
XX               123 [Stepper Here]
```

I tried adding HorizontalOptions to the second label but it doesn't seem to move it in front of the stepper.

Can someone give me some ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know xaml very well but it seems you have not defined row and columns definition, and you are not settings in which position of the grid you are inserting the stacklayout and the stepper.[Placing_Views_in_a_Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/#Placing_Views_in_a_Grid)

Second, you should have a 1row, 2cols grid: add XX label to row0col0 and a StackLayout (with 123 and "stepper here") to row0col1 and try to set 123 HorizontalOptions to "End" and "stepper here" HorizontalOptions to "End"